# Android App crash after taking picture "Unable to find the default constructor" On LG 4G Stylus

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, android-camera

My app crash after taking picture on LG 4G Stylus device.
It's work fine on Galaxy nexus, Galaxy S4 , LG 4G.

I can't put the finger on it and it's driving me crazy...

I'm using a viewpager for my image and using theses manifest config :

```
<activity android:name="easydeal_android.MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this !

Here is the exception : `Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to find the default constructor on type EasyDeal_Android.FragmentDetailsVehicle.  Please provide the missing constructor. ---> Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.`

Here is the trace :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to find the default constructor on type EasyDeal_Android.FragmentDetailsVehicle.  Please provide the missing constructor. ---> Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.
Java.Lang.Error: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Error' was thrown.
  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.lang.Error: Java callstack:
    at mono.android.TypeManager.n_activate(Native Method)
    at mono.android.TypeManager.Activate(TypeManager.java:7)
    at md56d2061e530d4ae630a81127536162064.FragmentDetailsVehicle.<init>(FragmentDetailsVehicle.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:611)
    at android.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:104)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1775)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:946)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:257)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:58)
    at md56d2061e530d4ae630a81127536162064.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at md56d2061e530d4ae630a81127536162064.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x00028>
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) <0x000e7>
at Android.App.Activity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x001cb>
at EasyDeal_Android.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x0001f>
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0005b>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.1f7fe7fe-50ae-47b3-b6d7-d47312e8dfe6 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>
    at md56d2061e530d4ae630a81127536162064.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at md56d2061e530d4ae630a81127536162064.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
    ... 4 more
```

**EDIT :**

It did resolve the issue but it still crash with this line after taking more than one picture :

```
10-23 15:57:56.783   839  1707 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{2380813b u0 adnt.easydeal/md56d2061e530d4ae630a81127536162064.MainActivity}
10-23 15:57:56.793   839  1682 I ActivityManager: Process adnt.easydeal (pid 2787) has died
10-23 15:57:56.793   839  1682 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{2e8c2d28 u0 adnt.easydeal/md56d2061e530d4ae630a81127536162064.MainActivity t2019}: app died, no saved state
```

Comment: Post the code of `FragmentDetailsVehicle`.

Comment: you cannot have a non-empty constructor for a fragment. if you need to pass information in your need to use `setArguments` and pass a bundle

Comment: @tyczj of course he can, but he also needs empty one.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski well he can but it is very bad practice plus values dont stay around with orientation changes like they do with bundles

Comment: @tyczj but who told your constructor cannot call `setArgument()`? :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Seems you got custom constructor in your `FragmentDetailsVehicle` class, but then you also need to hace the default c'tor (argument-less), which you gave to add to your Fragment class by hand. It must exist even if it does nothing:

```java
public FragmentDetailsVehicle() {}
```

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

> **All subclasses of Fragment must include a public no-argument
> constructor.** The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class
> when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able
> to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the no-argument
> constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some
> cases during state restore.

Comment: Still having problem after : 
10-23 15:57:56.793   839  1682 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{2e8c2d28 u0 adnt.easydeal/md56d2061e530d4ae630a81127536162064.MainActivity t2019}: app died, no saved state